# Java Heap Space: Applets

Tags: java, applet, heap-memory, appletviewer

I had to write a program to work for a 3000*3000 matrix.
It was working only up to 600*600.

So I ran my program by increasing heap size by `java -Xms64m -Xmx1024m <class_name>`
Because initially the `OutOfMemoryError` was occurring.
That solved the problem.

Now this same program is used to plot values in Applets.
So I made a package and imported it.
But then the same error was coming as you can't *run* an applet.

You can only type `javac class_name.java` and `appletviewer class_name.java`.

So there was no way I could increase heap size.
So I purposely put a `main()` function...which calculated the values to be plotted(stored in an array).

And the applet would print them.
And the array was static and global.

Then I compiled (`javac class_name.java`)and ran(`java -Xms64m -Xmx1024m <class_name>`) and then typed `appletviewer class_name.java`.

But 0,0,0,... got displayed.
Basically the default values of int array.

As though the `main()` function never ran.
Even though array was global.

Ultimately, I just need a `main()` function... and some variable that stores values and retains them when `ppletviewer class_name.java` is typed.

Is there any way to do this?
Or else to increase heap size for applets?

Because when I type the logic in `init()` or `paint()` function the same error comes (`OutOfMemoryError`)

Comment: Did you try googling with "increase heap for applets"? If you do this for end-users sorry you have no way. You can't force users to change their system settings to see your masterpiece.

Comment: Try reading the answers to the last question you asked on this topic... :P There is no point answering if you won't read them.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify JVM parameters in the HTML which contains the applet, e.g.

```
<APPLET archive="applet.jar" code="ClassName" width="300" height="300">
    <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xms64m -Xmx1024m">
</APPLET>
```

See [Oracle's documentation on applet deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html)

Comment: This is assuming of course that you are running in the context of a browser (rather than appletviewer).

Comment: No the main purpose is not for a browser but just to display data in a graph.

Im a little new to java,so just to be clear,the above code should have class name as ""ClassName" and is saved in a file called applet.jar?